# How do I fscanf without knowing the float length?

Tags: c++, c, decimal, scanf

I want to scan a data-file for "G1" followed by X, Y and Z coordinates given in floats, but the coordinates are represented with varying amount of decimal places. Three lines in the file could look like, where the first and third contain the coordinates:

```
    G1X59.7421875Y60.2578125
    M101S3F12
    G1X50.25
```

**Does anyone know how to `fscanf` a float with such unpredictable nature?**
When I look at the results (the `printf()`'s) the numbers don't match the file. I expect that the `fscanf` scans "through" the short floats, as they are not printed.

My code for traversing throug the lines: Note the function call to `find_arg()`, where I think the problem lies.

```
char line[LINE_LENGHT];
int G1, X, Y, Z, F, junk= 0;
float fdx, fdy, fdz;

while(!feof(file_gcode)){
   for (i = 0; i < LINE_LENGHT; i++){
      fscanf(file_gcode, "%c", &line[i]);
      if ((line[i-1] == 'G')&&(line[i] == '1')) {
         G1 ++;
         while (line[i] != '\n'){
            if( (line[i] == 'X') || (line[i]==('Y')) || (line[i]==('Z')) || (line[i] == ('F')) ) {
               find_arg(line[i]);
            }
            i ++;
            fscanf(file_gcode, "%c", &line[i]);
         }
         printf("X = %f, Y = %f, Z = %f \n", fdx, fdy, fdz);
      }
   }
}
printf("-------------------\n");
printf("G1's : %i\n", G1);
printf("X's : %i\n", X);
printf("Y's : %i\n", Y);
printf("Z's : %i\n", Z);
printf("F's : %i\n", F);
printf("other's : %i\n", junk);
printf("-------------------\n");
}

int find_arg(char c){
   if (c == 'X'){
      X ++;
      fscanf(file_gcode, "%f", &fdx);
   }
   else if(c == 'Y'){
      Y ++;
      fscanf(file_gcode, "%f", &fdy);
   }
   else if(c == 'Z'){
      Z ++;
      fscanf(file_gcode, "%f", &fdz);
   }
   else if(c == 'F'){
      F ++;
   }
   else junk ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float x, y, z;
int nread;
nread = fscanf(fp, "G1X%fY%fZ%f", &x, &y, &z);
```

`nread` will be the number of coordinates scanned. So if the line only has `X` and `Y` it will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strtok` to parse the input line - this would split out the bit of the string you care about. It removes some of the dependence on format of the string - but if your string format is well known, @Barmar's solution should work fine.

Something like this could be a workable alternative :

```
nextLine = fgets(fp);
// check line has "G1" in it:
if(strstr(nextLine, "G1)!=NULL) {
// look for 'X':
  strtok(nextLine, "X");
// find the thing between 'X' and 'Y':
  xString = strtok(NULL, "Y");
  if(xString != NULL) sscanf(xString, "%f", &xCoordinate);
// find the thing to the end of the line:
  yString = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  if(yString != NULL) sscanf(yString, "%f", &yCoordinate);
}
```